# Spring WebSecurity how to use 2 loginForm

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websecurity

I created two login forms in Spring Web Security. (User, Admin) However, if login fails on the user login page, it returns to the user login page, but if the login fails on the admin login page, it will return to the user login page instead of the admin login page. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

```
httpSecurity
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations())
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/registerUser", "/saveUser", "/admin")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/admin")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login-process")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/center", true)
            .failureUrl("/Admin/admin?error=ture")
            .failureHandler(failureHandler())
            .permitAll();

    httpSecurity.formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login-process")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/center", true)
            //.failureUrl("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login.html?error=true")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .rememberMe()
            .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
            .key(REMEMBER_ME_TOKEN)
            .tokenValiditySeconds(Math.toIntExact(Duration.ofDays(30).getSeconds()))
            .userDetailsService(userService);
```

Comment: I think the problem could appear here - `.failureUrl("/Admin/admin?error=true")`.
`true` - not `ture`

Comment: Then can I change true to not-true? I'll try.

Comment: not working not true

Comment: you have a typo: not `tURe`, fix to the `true`

Comment: I fixed true.. but now working actually